# Add empty space

Tags: spacing

I have the following code

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\underline{Verschiebare Ger{\"a}te}



\begin{equation*}
P_j(t,s_j) = \begin{cases}
    Q_{j,Standby} & \text{for } t < s_j \\
        Q_j(t-s_j) & \text{for  }s_j \leq t\leq s_j+p_j  \\
        Q_{j,Standby} & \text{for  } t>s_j+p_j 
   \end{cases}
    \end{equation*}

    mit

  \begin{align*}    
  s_j &= r_j+ \Delta t\\
      \Delta t &\leq tDoF
   \end{align*}

\noindent   
\underline{Beobachtbare Ger{\"a}te und Grundlast}

 \begin{align*}
P_{Beobachtbar}(t) & \rightarrow \text{nicht steuerbar, daher vorgegeben} \\
P_{Grundlast}(t) & \rightarrow \text{nicht steuerbar, daher vorgegeben}
\end{align*}

\noindent
\underline{Unterbrechbare Ger{\"a}te} \\
 $\rightarrow$ \text{ mit n verschiedenen Phasen (n beliebig aber fest)} 



\end{document}
```

And I would like to add more empty space before the underlined headlines. I tried `\\` and `\newline` but it did not work. How can I shift the headlines to the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\vspace{length}`

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\underline{Verschiebare Ger{\"a}te}
\begin{equation*}
P_j(t,s_j) = \begin{cases}
    Q_{j,Standby} & \text{for } t < s_j \\
        Q_j(t-s_j) & \text{for  }s_j \leq t\leq s_j+p_j  \\
        Q_{j,Standby} & \text{for  } t>s_j+p_j
   \end{cases}
    \end{equation*}
    mit
  \begin{align*}
  s_j &= r_j+ \Delta t\\
      \Delta t &\leq tDoF
   \end{align*}

\vspace{1cm}   %%<-----------------here
\noindent
\underline{Beobachtbare Ger{\"a}te und Grundlast}
 \begin{align*}
P_{Beobachtbar}(t) & \rightarrow \text{nicht steuerbar, daher vorgegeben} \\
P_{Grundlast}(t) & \rightarrow \text{nicht steuerbar, daher vorgegeben}
\end{align*}

\vspace{1cm}   %%<-----------------here
\noindent
\underline{Unterbrechbare Ger{\"a}te} \\
 $\rightarrow$ \text{ mit n verschiedenen Phasen (n beliebig aber fest)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Generally leaving empty line before and after `equation` like environments is discouraged. But here, to use `\vspace{1cm}` you will need a blank line before it.